# Js parse sql and extract table name alias

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a sql query and i want to extract table alias。
for example:

```
select * from t_1 a join t_2 b on a.id = b.t_id where a.words = ? and b.words = ?
```

the result I expected

> a: t_1, b: t_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex match approach to capture every table name and alias.

```js
var sql = "select * from t_1 join t_2 b on t_1.id = b.t_id where t_1.words = ? and b.words = ?";
var aliases = sql.match(/(?<=\b(?:from|join) )\w+(?: (?!\bjoin\b)\w+)?/g);
aliases.forEach(x => console.log((x.split(" ")[1] ? x.split(" ")[1] : x.split(" ")[0]) + ": " + x.split(" ")[0]));
```

Note that in general to do what you want would require a formal SQL *parser*.  Regex alone is not suitable, and it would take hundreds of lines of code, most likely more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer，this code can work，but some table have no alias，what to do in this case

Comment: @chenyinmu You need to tell me what to do in this case.

Comment: in this sql，select * from t_1 join t_2 b on t_1.id = b.t_id where t_1.words = ? and b.words = ?，t_1 have no alias, the result i expected  t_1: t_1, b: t_2

Comment: I have made an edit, but will not make further edits.  You should really invest some time into using a SQL parser, and JS may not be the best language to be using.

Comment: you are right. regex is not a good solution, thanks a lot.